# Get SUM with GROUP BY and additional columns without grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get SUM of all `orders` and `revenue` grouped by `campaign_id` and `report_date` and `sku` (it's PK). Next statement will work:

```
select sum(orders) as orders_total, sum(revenue) as  revenue_total, campaign_id, report_date 
from table
group by campaign_id, report_date
```

But I also want to add additional column to result: `product_name`. How to add this column without grouping by `product_name`?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table (
    sku int8 NOT NULL,
    product_name text NULL,
    orders int4 NULL,
    revenue numeric(19,2) NULL,
    campaign_id int8 NOT NULL,
    report_date date NOT NULL,
    keyword text,
    CONSTRAINT campaign_brand_shelf_orders_stats_pk PRIMARY KEY (sku, campaign_id, report_date, keyword)
);
```

Sample data:

```
campaign_id     sku         product_name    keyword     orders      revenue         report_date
157836          136253279   Product1        bath        10          2500            2021-05-03
157836          136253279   Product1        cream face  1           250             2021-05-03
```

Expected:

```
campaign_id     sku         product_name      orders_total      revenue_total       report_date
157836          136253279   Product1          11                2750                2021-05-03
```

Comment: pls post sample data and expected result.

Comment: Please add table definition, sample data and desired output by editing your question

Comment: Added additional info.

Comment: why don't you want grouping by `product_name`?  in your example it seems it is what your are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function for implementing it

```
select sum(orders) over (partition by campaign_id, report_date ) as orders_total, 
sum(revenue) over (partition by campaign_id, report_date )  as  revenue_total, 
campaign_id, report_date ,<other columns>
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query

```
SELECT campaign_id,sku,product_name,orders_total,revenue_total,report_date
FROM 
   (SELECT campaign_id,sku,product_name,
       sum(orders) OVER (partition BY campaign_id, report_date) as orders_total,
       sum(revenue) OVER (partition BY campaign_id, report_date) as revenue_total,
       report_date ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY campaign_id) as ROWNUMBER
    FROM table) T
WHRER ROWNUMBER = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have one product name per group, you can just add it to the `group by`:

```
select sum(orders) as orders_total, sum(revenue) as  revenue_total, 
       campaign_id, report_date, product_name
from table
group by campaign_id, report_date, product_name;
```

If there can be multiple product names and you want an arbitrary one, use an aggregation function:

```
select sum(orders) as orders_total, sum(revenue) as  revenue_total, 
       campaign_id, report_date, max(product_name) as product_name
from table
group by campaign_id, report_date;
```

If there can be multiple product names, and you want all of them, use arrays or strings:

```
select sum(orders) as orders_total, sum(revenue) as  revenue_total, 
       campaign_id, report_date, array_agg(distinct product_name) as product_names
from table
group by campaign_id, report_date;
```